# Multi-enterprise Analysis Services - can it be done?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssas

My company (a small software-as-a-service provider in the healthcare IT industry) is currently building a hosted BI solution to offer all of our clients. The deadlines have been moved up significantly and we have very little time to choose a platform, but since our company is heavily invested in .NET/SQL Server, SSAS seems like a natural choice. However, SSAS's deployment model appears geared towards single-enterprise internal solutions.

We have a somewhat different requirement. We will have a few data marts built on publically available data that all clients should be able to see (call them A and B) and a number of client data marts (call them C-Z). C-Z will need to be identical in function but completely isolated from each other (some of our data will be HIPAA-protected or business-sensitive for our clients).

We have previous experience with Pentaho, which seems to have the same single-enterprise model as SSAS, and the solution was a fairly messy hack involving multiple VMs and proxies (though part of that can be attributed to our head sysadmin at the time).

So my questions are:

- Is the model we need reasonably achievable in SSAS?
- If so, what is the best approach? Links to documentation would be appreciated, as Google is turning up scant little that seems relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is actually much easier than it sounds. After building your project, BIDS spits out a set of ASSL scripts, which, being XML, means that multiple automated deployments of the same database are entirely possible.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms129318%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

We do this.  We use LAMP (Linux, Apache, Python and MySQL) mostly and some FLEX/Air/BlazeDS stuff, also.

We're providing multiple-customer Software As A Service (SAAS).

We don't offer SQL Server Analysis Service, since we don't use any Microsoft products.  However, I think our approach may apply to what you're doing.

We have an Apache configuration that partitions each incoming customer request to a different back-end server.  In our case, there are many backends in Django as well as Glassfish.

Each back-end server is separate.  Currently, they run on a few VM's, but we can migrate the various components around to different VM's, leaving Apache as the front-end gateway that redirects requests.